# Ubuntu 16.04 splash screen freeze

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, plymouth

After a little while of having Ubuntu 16.04 (which I upgraded from 15.04) I keep on getting the splash screen to freeze after a few animations cycle of the dots where it end up like this:

[image: like this]

and whenever I press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to see what is going on, I get this:

[image: this]

I google solutions but most of them would only work when I have access to the Linux terminal (which I don't as it stops at the splash screen and I have to reboot/shutdown my PC).

I tried to remove the "quiet splash" as well as adding changing the GFX mode in the kernel editor but nothing works and the only change was when I had a purple blank screen.

I tried to the thing where I execute `sudo init 1` on the root terminal (the one that can be access after going on the advanced options from the GRUB menu) but it also end up in changing nothing.

I tried to go through the fsk and the package repair options of the GRUB menu but none of them seems to solve the problem.

Also my PC is on a dual boot Win10 64-bit/Ubuntu 16.04 with Win10 on `(hd0, 2)` and Ubuntu on `(hd1, 6)`:

[image]

How can I get it to work ?

Comment: Do you know what you did, or what changed, before this started happening? Did you install certain software or hardware or edit configuration files?

Comment: Nope, the only changes apart from the distro upgrade were some package update (with `apt-get update` of course) and that's it.

Comment: Plymouth and GDM? Not good. Heck, I think GDM should not be normally present on usual Ubuntu (which uses lightdm), but you have GDM enabled (not just installed)

Comment: You should try disabling Plymouth. `systemctl disable plymouth.service` and whichever command Ubuntu uses to update initramfs (so plymouth doesn't load very early either)

Comment: This is unlikely to be related to grub. Your machine is already booted, where it fails is in trying to start up the desktop/terminal session. What I'd suggest is getting to try to chroot into the broken system from a livecd/liveusb. Ice your in a chroot, try checking if you've got broken apt packages. Were you able to boot into recovery mode?

Comment: @LieRyan I was able to get into the recovery mode but no ways to boot into Ubuntu from there.